# Applying function in R with multiple arguments using apply or ddplyr

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Group Variable Value 
A     val1     1 
A     val2     2  
A     val3     3  
B     val1     2  
B     val2     3  
B     val3     4  
C     val1     2  
C     val2     3  
C     val3     5
```

and I want to apply a simple weighted function that takes in all three values for each group at different weights, like this:

```
calcWeightedVal<-function(val1,val2,val3){ 

  result<-(val1+(2*val2)+(3*val3)) 
  return(result) 
 }
```

How do I best apply the function (using apply or ddplyr or whatever) to get the weighted value for each group summarized in a dataframe like this:

```
Group Weighted_Value 
A     14 
B     20  
C     23
```

I tried ddplyr but wasn't sure how to pass a custom function with multiple arguments.

-Justin

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense. Why would you have `val1` as an argument but within the function call `pct1`? Anyway, besides a "plyr" approach, you can easily do this with `aggregate` in base R as follows: `aggregate(Value ~ Group, mydf, function(x) x[1]+(2*x[2])+(3*x[3]))`

Comment: Also, the `Variable` column in your input dataset is probably different from the `Variable` column in your output dataset. I'm not sure why your output dataset even has a `Variable` column, actually.

Comment: I changed the function to include val1,2, etc (instead of pct1, 2 ,3). Sorry about that. I can give the aggregate a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options to consider.

Option 1: `ddply` with no custom function.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mydf, .(Group), summarize, V1=(Value[1] + (2 * Value[2]) + (3 * Value[3])))
  Group V1
1     A 14
2     B 20
3     C 23
```

Option 2: `ddply` with a custom function. Note the modifications from your function.

```
calcWeightedVal <- function(x) {
  x <- x$Value
  x[1] + (2 * x[2]) + (3 * x[3])
}
ddply(mydf, .(Group), calcWeightedVal)
```

Option 3: `aggregate` from base R.

```
aggregate(Value ~ Group, mydf, function(x) x[1] + (2 * x[2]) + (3 * x[3]))
```

All will yield the same answer. I don't know how you really want to deal with the "Variable" column though. I don't see how it relates to the aggregated output.

Comment: I was wrong to include the "Variable" in the output column. I have modified the original question so it is clearer for other users.

Comment: One of the challenges I'm having now is with situations where there is an uneven number of values and they are not in order. For example, what if Group A has 'val3, val2, val2, val3, val1, val1'. It would be fine to average the individual values together (eg val1=avg(all val 1's) in the function but they would need to be in the correct order. Not quite sure how to do this.  This could be a separate post I guess

Comment: @user2900006, hard to tell, but it sure sounds like a separate post :)